# sscanf reads string in ( )

Tags: c, string, scanf

this question bothers me this few days.
I want to read a string for example, input = (-0.001999,-0.919191,-0.777777,999999.999999)
using sscanf. And my code is

```
char x[10], y[10], z[10], angle[10];
sscanf( input+1, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^)]", &x, %y, &z, &angle);
printf("%s %s %s %s\n", x, y, z, angle);
```

the expected result is x=-0.001999 y=-0.919191 z=-0.777777 a=999999.999999

but my printf shows : x=-0.001999 y=-0.919191 z=999 a=999999.999999

can somebody help me figure out where the problem is ??

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angle is not big enough to hold the input data and thus z is getting overwritten.  Try this:

```
char x[80], y[80], z[80], angle[80];
```

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the odd buffer overflow and such, I get:

```
char input[] = "(-0.001999,-0.919191,-0.777777,999999.999999)";
char x[10], y[10], z[10], angle[14];
sscanf( input+1, "%9[^,],%9[^,],%9[^,],%13[^)]", x, y, z, angle);
printf("%s %s %s %s\n", x, y, z, angle);
```

and the output I get from this is:

```
-0.001999 -0.919191 -0.777777 999999.999999
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sscanf like should be `sscanf( input+1, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^)]", x, y, z, angle);` since your arrays are already pointers (and the y has a % in your example).  The other responder has solved the root problem.